# Releasing an audio endpoint from exclusive-mode use

Tags: windows, audio

I notice that in the Microsoft SDK audio samples, both of the Render/Exclusive examples will, for example, stop iTunes playing through my headphones (wholly expected), but when the example program has completed, iTunes is left in a kind of zombie state that requires it to be closed and restarted in order to play anything.

Is this normal, or a fault of iTunes (my version: 11.1.3.8)... or is there something an application should do to announce to other applications that its exclusive use of the endpoint has finished?

Comment: I have subsequently confirmed that audio played through YouTube also grinds to a halt in the same way, and my browser (Firefox) needs to be restarted for YouTube to resume normal play